# Ruby on rails default date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to create a column or to change one to type date with default format?
something like:

```
def change
    change_column :mytable, :mydate, :date [:default]="%d/%m/%Y"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge no. But why on Earth would you want to do that?

Rails will pull out a date and automagically make it a Date/Time (according to your column type) object. If you need to display your date differently I strongly suggest the use of strftime like so:

```
@foo.created_at.strftime('%F')
```

Here's a list of the different options: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

### Update

Make use of decorators with Draper: https://github.com/drapergem/draper

I would recommend renaming the method but for now if you don't want to you could simply override it doing this:

```
# app/decorators/article_decorator.rb
class ArticleDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def published_at
    source.published_at.strftime("%A, %B %e")
  end
end
```

You would it like so:

```
@article.decorate.published_at
```

In it's default state, the date returned will not be formatted which is fine.

If you have to do `where("date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') >= ?",fdate`, you're doing it wrong. Again, stick to the default format.

Comment: i need to put the date in a lot of views, so each time i want to show it i should add the 
    .strftime('%F')

also, i have this query:
    fdate = params[:date].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    @latestPools = Pool.order('-id').where(latestQuery).where("date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') >= ?",fdate).limit(50)
and of course it doesnt work, should i change the param format? or is there an easier way?

thank you for your help